# Finding out presence of loops(interconnections) in a line

Tags: python, math, multidimensional-array, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I have a set of 2D coordinates. It can be positive, negative and also those are in fractions as well. So the points are like,

```
50.2345,-23.452
1.345,-14.206
```

so on and so forth. Now My question is if I plot these coordinates on a graph, how to determine whether the line would intersect to form a loop or would it remain as a zig zag line(without intersecting itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be calculated with a nested FOR loop.

Assume I have 5 points:
[0,0],[1,1],[2,1],[2,0],[0,1]

This gives us 4 Edges, the last of which will overlap the first. *edge*([0,0],[1,1]) will intersect with *edge*([2,0],[0,1]).

Iterate over each Edge (line segment) and test for intersection with all other line segments.

pseudocode:

```
 for(edge1 in edges)
 {   
     for(edge2 in edges)
     {
        if ( testIntersect(edge1,edge2) ) return true;
     }
 }
 return false;
```

Comment: How does python allows us to create edges ? 
All these are in terms of physical 2D coordinates right ?
Do you have any resource that you can share ?

Comment: "Edge" is just the term for a line connecting two points. I also hear the term "line segment," but substantially less often. All lines are defined by their end points: [x1,y1],[x2,y2].

Comment: Ya. I get it. I am trying to find a way to define a line segment in python and actually apply this concept. It seems like I will have to create an equation for the two lines and check if they are intersecting.. I guess there are no libraries for that.

Comment: line intersection is a basic equation, it would be simple to make a function that takes the 4 points and returns true or false